# How i can add Carousel from Bootstrap in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm beginner to ASP.NET Core MVC. I do not know how I can correctly use Bootstrap Carousel in a project. My image files are added to SQL Server, but only 1 file is stored in the database and only I can use it in the view.

Main model Product.cs:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage= "Name field can't be empty")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description field can't be empty")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price field can't be empty")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category field can't be empty")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class ProductCreateViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name field can't be empty")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description field can't be empty")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price field can't be empty")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category field can't be empty")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
    }
```

Create and Upload methods in Controller:

```
            [HttpGet]
            public ViewResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Create(ProductCreateViewModel model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string uniqueFileName = ProcessUploadFile(model);
                    var newProduct = new Product
                    {
                        Name = model.Name,
                        Description = model.Description,
                        Price = model.Price,
                        Category = model.Category,
                        Image = uniqueFileName,
                    };

                    _repository.Add(newProduct);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = newProduct.ProductID });
                }
                return View();
            }

            private string ProcessUploadFile(ProductCreateViewModel model)
            {
               string uniqueFileName = null;
               if (model.Images != null && model.Images.Count > 0)
               {
                  foreach (IFormFile photo in model.Images)
                  {
                    var uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
                    uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + photo.FileName;
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                      photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                 }
              }

            return uniqueFileName;
            }
```

View file Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="card card-columns p-2 bg-light">
    <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group row m-1">
            <label asp-for="Images" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input multiple asp-for="Images" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                    <label class="custom-file-label">Choose PNG File...</label>
                </div>
        </div>
    <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

View file Detail.cshtml:

```
@model Product
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee Details";
    var photoPath = "~/Images/" + (Model.Image ?? "someProduct.jpg");
}

    <div class="card card-columns m-1 p-1" >
        <form id="@Model.ProductID" asp-action="AddToCart"
              asp-controller="Cart" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProductID"/>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">

                        <div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel--item active">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" alt="" src="@photoPath" asp-append-version="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()" />

                    <div class="m-1 text-center btn-block">
                        <a asp-action="List" asp-controller="Product" class="btn btn-warning m-1">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

View model ProductEditViewModel.cs:

```
public class ProductEditViewModel : ProductCreateViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ExistingPhotoPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit method in Controler:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Edit(int productId)
        {
            Product product = _repository.GetProduct(productId);
            ProductEditViewModel productEditViewModel = new ProductEditViewModel
            {
                Id = product.ProductID,
                Name = product.Name,
                Category = product.Category,
                Description = product.Description,
                Price = product.Price,
                ExistingPhotoPath = product.Images
            };

            return View(productEditViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(ProductEditViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Product product = _repository.GetProduct(model.Id);
                product.Name = model.Name;
                product.Price = model.Price;
                product.Description = model.Description;
                product.Category = model.Category;
                if (model.Images != null)
                {
                    if (model.ExistingPhotoPath != null)
                    {
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath,
                            "images", model.ExistingPhotoPath);
                        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                    }

                    product.Images = ProcessUploadFile(model);
                }

                _repository.SaveProduct(product);
                TempData["message"] = $"{product.Name} has been edit";
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, image carousel on the product Detail.cshtml or save multiple picture paths or names to the database. Please include all relevant code (such as model, viewmodel, as well as the complete view code and the back-end code of the Detail.cshtml you tried).

Comment: Ok, i added them. I think maybe add two properties image2 and image3 in the model and include them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `Image` property in the `Product` from `string` to `List<Image>`.

Here is a complete modification that you could refer to :

Product.cs

```
 public class Product
{
    ...

    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

Upload and ProductDetail methods in Controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ProductDetail(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var product = await _context.Product
            .Include(p=>p.Images)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProductID == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(product);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(ProductCreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<Image> images = ProcessUploadFile(model);
            var newProduct = new Product
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Description = model.Description,
                Price = model.Price,
                Category = model.Category,
                Images = images,
            };

            _context.Add(newProduct);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = newProduct.ProductID });
        }
        return View();
    }

    private List<Image> ProcessUploadFile(ProductCreateViewModel model)
    {
        var ImageList = new List<Image>();
        if (model.Images != null && model.Images.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (IFormFile photo in model.Images)
            {
                var Image = new Image();
                var uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
                Image.ImageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + photo.FileName;
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, Image.ImageName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                ImageList.Add(Image);
            }
        }

        return ImageList;
    }
```

ProductDetail.cshtml

```
@model Product


<div class="card card-columns m-1 p-1">
  <form id="@Model.ProductID" asp-action="AddToCart"
      asp-controller="Cart" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProductID" />
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">

            <div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Images.Count; i++)
                     {
                        var photoPath = "~/Images/" + (Model.Images[i].ImageName ?? "someProduct.jpg");
                        <div class="carousel--item active">
                             <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" alt="" src="@photoPath" asp-append-version="true" />
                        </div>
                    }

                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()" />

        <div class="m-1 text-center btn-block">
            <a asp-action="List" asp-controller="Product" class="btn btn-warning m-1">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's work ! Can I ask you for advice? My editing method is not working properly.